# SQL with Multiple Left Joins

Tags: mysql, sql, selection

Using: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/sakila/en/

I'm trying to write a query to count the number of films each actor has acted in by category.

Would appreciate any pointers or advice.

Here is my code so far (it counts the films correctly for one category when I take out the second LEFT JOIN section):

```
SELECT actor.first_name, actor.last_name, 
COUNT(subset.film_id) AS action,
COUNT(subset2.film_id) AS animation
FROM actor
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT film.film_id, actor.actor_id 
FROM actor
INNER JOIN film_actor
ON film_actor.actor_id = actor.actor_id
INNER JOIN film 
ON film.film_id = film_actor.film_id
INNER JOIN film_category 
ON film_category.film_id = film.film_id
INNER JOIN category 
ON category.category_id = film_category.category_id
WHERE category.name = 'Action') AS subset 
ON subset.actor_id = actor.actor_id
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT film.film_id, actor.actor_id 
FROM actor
INNER JOIN film_actor
ON film_actor.actor_id = actor.actor_id
INNER JOIN film 
ON film.film_id = film_actor.film_id
INNER JOIN film_category 
ON film_category.film_id = film.film_id
INNER JOIN category 
ON category.category_id = film_category.category_id
WHERE category.name = 'Animation') AS subset2
ON subset2.actor_id = actor.actor_id
GROUP BY actor.actor_id
ORDER BY actor.last_name ASC;
```

Comment: The query will cartesian, if an actor is in 2 actions films and 2 animation films, there will be 4 rows coming back, take out the counts / group by and you should start to see the cartesian

Answer (score 1):

The query you've got seems awfully complicated if all you want is to get a count of movies per actor and category.

This query:

```
SELECT 
    actor.first_name, actor.last_name, category.name, 
    COUNT(*) as CountPerCategory
FROM actor
JOIN film_actor ON film_actor.actor_id = actor.actor_id
JOIN film ON film.film_id = film_actor.film_id
JOIN film_category ON film_category.film_id = film.film_id
JOIN category ON category.category_id = film_category.category_id
GROUP BY actor.first_name, actor.last_name, category.name;
```

would give you an output like:

```
Firstname, Lastname, Category, CountPerCategory
Clint      Eastwood  Animation 1
Clint      Eastwood  Action    15
```

but if you want the counts per category in different columns you could exploit the fact that MySQL returns 1 for true conditions and test that the category matches and use sum (this could also be don't with a case expression in a more portable way), like this:

```
SELECT 
    actor.first_name, actor.last_name, category.name
    , SUM(category.name = 'Animation') as CountOfAnimation
    , SUM(category.name = 'Action') as CountOfAction
FROM actor
JOIN film_actor ON film_actor.actor_id = actor.actor_id
JOIN film ON film.film_id = film_actor.film_id
JOIN film_category ON film_category.film_id = film.film_id
JOIN category ON category.category_id = film_category.category_id
GROUP BY actor.first_name, actor.last_name, category.name;
```

which would give a result like:

```
Firstname, Lastname, CountOfAnimation, CountOfAction
Clint      Eastwood  1                 15
```

Note that if a film belongs to multiple categories it would get counted once for each category, which might be what you want (or not).

Answer (score 0):

This should give you the count for all actors, with all categories they have been associated with:

```
SELECT actor.first_name, actor.last_name, category.name
, COUNT(DISTINCT film.film_id)
FROM actor
LEFT JOIN film_actor ON film_actor.actor_id = actor.actor_id
LEFT JOIN film ON film.film_id = film_actor.film_id
LEFT JOIN film_category ON film_category.film_id = film.film_id
LEFT JOIN category ON category.category_id = film_category.category_id
GROUP BY actor.first_name, actor.last_name, category.name
;
```

If you only want specific ones, add on this after the `GROUP BY` line:

```
HAVING category.name IN ('Action', 'Animation')
```

If you only want actors with those categories, change the `LEFT JOIN`s to `INNER JOIN`s and/or change the aforementioned HAVING to a WHERE (and reposition it accordingly).

Answer (score 0):

I agree, that query looks very complicated and by using 2 derived tables it'll probably run slowly as well. This query will give the unique films in each category and will not duplicate the results as there are no many to many joins.
It will slow down as you add categories however because it has to scan the table multiple times but it will give accurate results and as long as your table isn't too large it should be fine.

You probably don't need the distinct's, but if for whatever reason someone had the same category on a film twice (or something similar) this will remove room for error.

```
select a.first_name, a.last_name
, (
select count(distinct f.id) 
from film f 
join film_actor fa on fa.film_id=f.film_id
join film_category fc on fc.film_id=f.film_id
join category c ON c.category_id = fc.category_id
where c.name='Animation'
and fa.actor_id=a.actor_id
) as unique_animation_films
, (
select count(distinct f.id) 
from film f 
join film_actor fa on fa.film_id=f.film_id
join film_category fc on fc.film_id=f.film_id
join category c ON c.category_id = fc.category_id
where c.name='Action'
and fa.actor_id=a.actor_id
) as unique_action_films
from actor a
```